# Почему vsftpd создает файлы с правами 0

Tags: ftp

на сервере стоит debian, фтп сервер vsftpd, web сервер апач, при создании/копировании файла он создается с правами 0.в настройках.

```
file_open_mode=0777local_umask=0777
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`umask` - если мне не изменяет память, должна быть **(почти)** обратной к правам, которые вы хотите получить у созданных файлов. Читайте [вот здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask), кажется, понятно.

Comment: менял umask по всякому, перезагружал ftp сервер, результат тот же. перезагрузил всю систему стало работать как надо.. видимо проблема в debian а в чем именно так останется загадкой.